# Android: Can't insert data in mysql using php pdo

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdo

I am new to android development. I am making an app where the user needs to register themselves from the app itself. The problem that I get is I can't insert the record once again after it is inserted once. In other words, I am failing to insert the records if i insert one time from my device. I need to wait for atleast 15 min to insert another record. I am using PHP PDO to insert the records in the mysql database.

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
$nm = $_GET['nm'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['pass'];

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname; dbname=database", "username", "passwoprd");
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    try {
        $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Entrepreneurs(entFullName, entEmailId, entPassword)
                VALUES(:name, :email, :passWord)");
        $query->bindParam(':name', $nm);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $query->bindParam(':passWord', $password);
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "Some Exception Occured: <br />" . $ex->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Here's the java code:

```
package com.example.entrepreneurexpress.entrepreneurs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.entrepreneurexpress.R;

public class EntrepreneurRegister extends Activity {

    String extracted_email, extracted_password, extracted_fullName;
    EditText YourName, email, password;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.entrepreneur_register);

        ActionBar aBar = getActionBar();
        aBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Button btnEntClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEntRegClear);
        Button btnEntRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEntRegRegister);

        YourName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEntRegFullName);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEntRegEmailId);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEntRegPassword);

        btnEntClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (YourName.length() >= 1) {
                    YourName.setText("");
                }
                if (email.length() >= 1) {
                    email.setText("");
                }
                if (password.length() >= 1) {
                    password.setText("");
                }
            }           
        });

        btnEntRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(YourName.length() < 1 || email.length() < 1 || password.length() < 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Fill In All The Details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    new RegisterTask().execute("register");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EntrepreneurRegister.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Processing..");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering Yourself With Us.......");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            extracted_email = email.getText().toString();
            extracted_fullName = YourName.getText().toString();
            extracted_password = password.getText().toString();

            String requesturl = "http://mehul.wink.ws/insertEntrepreneur.php?nm=" + extracted_fullName + 
                    "&email=" + extracted_email + "&pass=" + extracted_password;

            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI website;
                website = new URI(requesturl);
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(website);
                client.execute(request);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(pDialog != null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sucessfully Inserted !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeEntrepreneur.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I came to know what the error is:

When I type the name in android application with spaces like `FirstName LastName`, it does not get inserted but when I don't insert any space while typing name like `FirstNameLastName`, it gets inserted.

Now the question is: How do I solve above error ?

Kindly help me with this query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL encode the inputs you pass in your URL strings. Change this

```
String requesturl = "http://mehul.wink.ws/insertEntrepreneur.php?nm=" + extracted_fullName + 
                "&email=" + extracted_email + "&pass=" + extracted_password;
```

to something like

```
String requesturl = "http://mehul.wink.ws/insertEntrepreneur.php?nm=" + URLEncoder.encode(extracted_fullName= + 
                "&email=" + URLEncoder.encode(extracted_email) + "&pass=" + URLEncoder.encode(extracted_password);
```

Also consider changing the HTTP verb from GET to e.g. POST. GET is semantically wrong for a request that modifies something.

Comment: Thanks dude.. you saved my day. Can you please post the tutorial link for inserting data from android using PHP PDO having `$_POST` method and not `$_GET`, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

check this PHP-PDO file output in localhost using POSTMan tool.
Try this link.[PHP - PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

change php file code

```
 <?php
 $nm = $_POST['nm'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['pass'];

  $con = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname; dbname=database", "username", "passwoprd");
  $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO Entrepreneurs(entFullName, entEmailId, entPassword)
            VALUES(:name, :email, :passWord)");
    $query->bindParam(':name', $nm);
    $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $query->bindParam(':passWord', $password);
    $query->execute();
}catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Some Exception Occured: <br />" . $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

and in java code, where you used requesturl...change it..

```
     String requesturl = "http://mehul.wink.ws/insertEntrepreneur.php?nm=extracted_fullName&email=extracted_email&pass=extracted_password"
```

Try this

Comment: If I insert manually by typing in the URL, it gets inserted. But if I insert from the app. it's not getting inserted.

Comment: try this...."http://mehul.wink.ws/insertEntrepreneur.php?" +"&nm=" + extracted_fullName + 
                    "&email=" + extracted_email + "&pass=" + extracted_password;

Comment: the output is as follows:
`extracted_fullName` `extracted_email` `extracted_password` in the database

Comment: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entFullName' cannot be null. i have found...You are passing null from Android. $nm is empty,null or 0